# FFMPEG error submitting a packet to the muxer

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp

I am attempting to stream video frames to a RTSP server using FFMPEG. I instantiate an ffmpeg pipeline in c++. There are times when the process works perfectly and other times I get the error Error submitting a packet to the muxer: Broken pipe. Error muxing a packet. What uis strange is that there are times when the stream works and times when it does not which leads me to believe that the FFMPEG parameters that I set are not necessarily incorrect.

I am using a mex function within MATLAB to take in a frame and stream it.

```
// Global variables
FILE* openPipeLine = NULL;

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[], int frameWidth, int frameHeight)
{

    Ptr<Mat> inputFrame = ocvMxArrayToImage_uint8(prhs[0], true);
    Mat processedFrame = *inputFrame;

    // Check if FFMPEG process has been started
    if (!openPipeLine)
    {
        openPipeLine = _popen("ffmpeg -report -f rawvideo -r 10 -video_size 1280x720 -pixel_format bgr24 -i pipe: -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream 2> log.txt", "wb");

    }

    // Write the frame data to the pipeline
    fwrite(processedFrame.data, 1, frameWidth * frameHeight * 3, openPipeLine);
    mexAtExit(exitFcn);
}
```

Below is the full report from the ffmpeg process. Do my operating system variables change from time to time which cause the stream to work at times and break at others? I am using Windows 10.

```
Log level: 48
Command line:
ffmpeg -report -f rawvideo -r 10 -video_size 1280x720 -pixel_format bgr24 -i pipe: -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream

  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-lib  libavutil      58. 16.101 / 58. 16.101
  libavcodec     60. 23.100 / 60. 23.100
  libavformat    60. 10.100 / 60. 10.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.101 / 60.  2.101
  libavfilter     9. 11.100 /  9. 11.100
  libswscale      7.  3.100 /  7.  3.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
Splitting the commandline.

Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: pipe:.
[rawvideo @ 00000182dba5efc0] Opening 'pipe:' for reading
[pipe @ 00000182dba611c0] Setting default whitelist 'crypto,data'
[rawvideo @ 00000182dba5efc0] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:65536 seeks:0 nb_streams:1
[rawvideo @ 00000182dba5efc0] All info found
[rawvideo @ 00000182dba5efc0] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 2764800 bytes read:2764800 seeks:0 frames:1
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 221184 kb/s
  Stream #0:0, 1, 1/10: Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24, 1280x720, 221184 kb/s, 10 tbr, 10 tbn
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url rtsp://192.168.0.2:8554/mystream.
Applying option vcodec (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument libx264.
Applying option pix_fmt (set pixel format) with argument yuv420p.
Applying option f (force format) with argument rtsp.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: rtsp://192.168.0.2:8554/mystream.
[out#0/rtsp @ 00000182dba72c00] No explicit maps, mapping streams automatically...
[vost#0:0/libx264 @ 00000182dba75cc0] Created video stream from input stream 0:0
Successfully opened the file.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
[rawvideo @ 00000182dba72700] PACKET SIZE: 2764800, STRIDE: 3840
detected 16 logical cores
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000182dba86180] Setting 'video_size' to value '1280x720'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000182dba86180] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '3'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000182dba86180] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/10'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000182dba86180] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '0/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000182dba86180] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '10/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000182dba86180] w:1280 h:720 pixfmt:bgr24 tb:1/10 fr:10/1 sar:0/1
[format @ 00000182dba86540] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p'
[auto_scale_0 @ 00000182dba869c0] w:iw h:ih flags:'' interl:0
[format @ 00000182dba86540] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scale_0' between the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'format'
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000182dba49040] query_formats: 4 queried, 2 merged, 1 already done, 0 delayed
[auto_scale_0 @ 00000182dba869c0] w:1280 h:720 fmt:bgr24 sar:0/1 -> w:1280 h:720 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 flags:0x00000004
[libx264 @ 00000182dba76080] using mv_range_thread = 24
[libx264 @ 00000182dba76080] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 AVX512
[libx264 @ 00000182dba76080] profile High, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 00000182dba76080] 264 - core 164 r3107 a8b68eb - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2023 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=22 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=10 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[tcp @ 00000182dc5ce480] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 00000182dc5ce480] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 00000182dc5ce480] Address 192.168.0.2 port 8554
[tcp @ 00000182dc5ce480] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 00000182dc5ce480] Address 192.168.0.2 port 8554
[tcp @ 00000182dc5ce480] Starting connection attempt to 192.168.0.2 port 8554
[tcp @ 00000182dc5ce480] Successfully connected to 192.168.0.2 port 8554
[rtsp @ 00000182dba72d00] SDP:
v=0

o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1

s=No Name

c=IN IP4 192.168.0.2

t=0 0

a=tool:libavformat 60.10.100

m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96

a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000

a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1; sprop-parameter-sets=Z2QAH6zZQFAFuhAAAAMAEAAAAwFA8YMZYA==,aOvjyyLA; profile-level-id=64001F

a=control:streamid=0


[rtp @ 00000182dc5cd040] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 00000182dba4b140] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 00000182dba4b140] end receive buffer size reported is 393216
[udp @ 00000182dc9bf040] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 00000182dc9bf040] end receive buffer size reported is 393216
Output #0, rtsp, to 'rtsp://192.168.0.2:8554/mystream':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf60.10.100
  Stream #0:0, 0, 1/90000: Video: h264, yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1280x720, q=2-31, 10 fps, 90k tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc60.23.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
[rawvideo @ 00000182dba72700] PACKET SIZE: 2764800, STRIDE: 3840
[rawvideo @ 00000182dba72700] PACKET SIZE: 2764800, STRIDE: 3840
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
[rawvideo @ 00000182dba72700] PACKET SIZE: 2764800, STRIDE: 3840
[rawvideo @ 00000182dba72700] PACKET SIZE: 2764800, STRIDE: 3840
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
[rawvideo @ 00000182dba72700] PACKET SIZE: 2764800, STRIDE: 3840   
[rawvideo @ 00000182dba72700] PACKET SIZE: 2764800, STRIDE: 3840
[libx264 @ 00000182dba76080] frame=   0 QP=21.34 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0   I:3600 P:0    SKIP:0    size=135901 bytes
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=25.0 size=       0kB time=-00:00:00.20 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
[vost#0:0/libx264 @ 00000182dba75cc0] Error submitting a packet to the muxer: Broken pipe
[out#0/rtsp @ 00000182dba72c00] Error muxing a packet
[out#0/rtsp @ 00000182dba72c00] Terminating muxer thread
[rawvideo @ 00000182dba72700] PACKET SIZE: 2764800, STRIDE: 3840
[libx264 @ 00000182dba76080] frame=   1 QP=18.29 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:2   I:2662 P:866  SKIP:72   size=54835 bytes
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=25.0 size=N/A time=-00:00:00.10 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
No more output streams to write to, finishing.

Conversion failed!
```

Comment: It appears that when the selected codec is mpeg4 instead of libx264 the stream works fine. The problem is that mpeg4 is not supported by other parts of my workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a fairly current build of ffmpeg? I've been streaming to Twitch (rtmp/flv) using ffmpeg for a few months without any problems, but for the past week or two I've apparently been suffering from the same problem. Randomly the error occurs and the stream drops.

```
[vost#0:1/copy @ 0x558a6e8afa40] Error submitting a packet to the muxer: Broken pipe
[out#0/flv @ 0x558a6ea08f40] Error muxing a packet
[out#0/flv @ 0x558a6ea08f40] Error writing trailer: Broken pipe
[out#0/flv @ 0x558a6ea08f40] Error closing file: Broken pipe
```

I always use updated ffmpeg binaries from [this repository](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases). Perhaps this problem was introduced in some current commit. I'm going to test using stable ffmpeg from my Linux distribution's repository to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Thank you for response. I am using the version from 14th August, 2023. This is the line from the log file that gives info on the build: ffmpeg version 2023-08-14-git-c704901324-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)

Answer (score 0):

I am having this issue for years, I think since 2020 with self compiled ffmpeg. Instead of last git release I also tried to compile stable releases (v4.4 etc) to avoid possible bugs

As a work around I m using a static binary from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

they work fine but they don't support vaapi (gpu encoding) and I m currently testing this out,  reason I m back with a compiled ffmpeg.  I just updated to the current ffmpeg svn built, and same thing happens than in the past